# Наследование с помощью new

Tags: javascript, ооп, объекты, прототипное-наследование

Есть код

```js
let variable=new FunctionConstructor();
```

Поскольку `variable` создана с помощью `new` и функции-конструктора `FunctionConstructor`, то `variable` получает все свойства и методы объекта функции `FunctionConstructor`, поскольку `variable` - это экземпляр класса (функции) `FunctionConstructor`, созданный с помощью `new`. Последнее утверждение правильное или нет.

Comment: У меня другой вопрос (речь о том, что `variable.__proto__=FunctionConstructor.prototype` не идет, речь идет о наследовании variable свойств и методов FunctionConstructor, поскольку variable экземпляр класса `FunctionConstructor`.

Comment: "свойство" `FunctionConstructor` — это `FunctionConstructor.test = 5;`. После вызова конструктора, `variable.test` будет undefined. Такое свойство можно достать через `console.log( variable.constructor.test );`